# How to scrape table database which only shows a limited number of rows HTML PYTHON

Tags: python, html

I am trying to scrape the [CPU Specs Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/) for a project.

The database has roughly 2000 entries but only shows around 50 rows at once, what is the best way to access the entire database should i try to find a way to iterate or is there some where i can call its API?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Perhaps a nice slow loop with `https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/?ajaxsrch=a` then b then c until z and then 0-1 and remove dupes.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed thanks

Comment: @mplungjan I am confused on how it goes through so a, b, c... z but what do you mean by 0-1?

Comment: in case there are codes that have numbers and not found with a-z - I meant 0-9

Comment: ok so with 36 checks i should get them all?

Comment: Try it. I do not know, but if you know to complete number, you can double check - make sure you do not hammer them and you may be violating a TOS

Comment: I have run through the 36 but it still misses things any ideas?

Comment: Nope. No suggestions - ask them?